# Need to be able to see rectangles being drawn in Processing using for loop

Tags: animation, processing

For a project I made a code that creates a computer wallpaper with icons.  One Icon I set to draw a loading bar when clicked (void mousePressed).  I want to be able to see the rectangle(loading bar)start at a determined location using RectMode(CORNER) and have the width increase every few seconds until the bar is about 3/4 full and then stop and remain.

please give suggestions
this draws the finished bar but i want to see each increment for a couple seconds

```
void setup(){
  size(800,600);
}

void mousePressed(){
  if (mousePressed && mouseX>width/4 && mouseX<width-width/4 && mouseY>height/3 && mouseY<height-    height/3){
  rectMode(CORNER);
  noStroke();
  fill(0,180,0,180);
  for( int r = 0; r <= 7; r++){
    if (r == 1)
      i = 50;
    rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    if (r == 2)
      i = 150;
    rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    if (r == 3)
      rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    i = 250;
    if (r == 4)
      rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    i = 350;
    if (r == 5)
      rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    i = 450;
    if (r == 6)
      rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    i = 550;
    if (r == 7)
      rect(width/2-348,height/2-35,i,height/8-4);
    i = 650;
} 
}

}
```

Comment: sorry deleted old one didn't see edit button  I am a new member

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
int time, myWidth;
boolean loading;

void setup(){
  size(800,600);
  loading = false;
  myWidth = 0;
}

void draw(){
  drawLoadingBar();
}

void drawLoadingBar(){

  if(myWidth < width/3){
    if(loading && millis()-time > 1000){
      rect(20, height/2, myWidth, 30);
      myWidth = myWidth + 10;          
      time = millis();
    }
  }

}

void mousePressed(){
  if(loading == false){
      time = millis();  
      loading = true;
  }
}
```

This code works by increasing the bar width by 10 every second after the first mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

Using loop is in processing defined by function `loop()` and can be stopped by `noLoop()` also I am using frameCount (contains the number of frames that have been displayed since the program started - each run of `draw()` function) to count percentage of loaded progress bar and to stop loading on 3/4 as you want.

```
boolean loading = false;
int fillX = 0;

void setup()
{
  size(300,300);
  background(0);
  noLoop();  
}

void draw()
{
  stroke(255);
  fill(0);
  rect(48, 137, 204, 25);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  rect(51, 140, fillX, 20);

  if(loading == true)
  {       
    fillX = ((frameCount%301) / 3 * 2);    
    if(frameCount%(300*0.75) == 0)
    {
      loading = false;
      noLoop();
      frameCount = 0;
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  loading = true;
  loop();
}
```

RectMode(CORNER) is default mode so the is no need to specify it unless you are using different modes within project.